# How do I find the number of elements X macro enum

Tags: c, enums, macros

```
#define ID_ENUM(X)                        \
    X(TEL_ID, 0x100)           \
    X(ING_ID, 0x200)             \
    X(HEARTBEAT, 0x206) \
    X(FRAME, 0x400)           \
    XFRAME2, 0x410)

#define X(name, id) name = id,

typedef enum tx_ids {
    ID_ENUM(X)
} tx_ids_t;

#undef X

    #define X(name, id) +1
uint8_t var_list = 0 + ID_ENUM(X);
    #undef X
```

I am trying to find the number elements in enum . My compiler has been throwing error as multiple definition for `var_list`. What is wrong with my program ?

The above is code is my actual code and tried to execute this in different platforms and I see the same error

Comment: Two problems: The first is that there's a typo in the `ID_ENUM` macro. The second problem is (I ***guess***) that you're defining the variable in a header file that is included into multiple [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). In the future please try to create a proper [mre], that you test first and then copy-paste into your questions.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes It was in the header file

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious problem of trying to declare a variable in a header, there's a better way for finding all the items in the enum. Since you assign each item a custom value, you can't use the otherwise handy, classic trick:

```c
typedef enum
{
  APPLES,
  ORANGES,
  FRUITS_N  // this one will be 2 so it can be used to determine the number of items
} fruit_n;
```

With X macros you can therefore make 2 different enums, one for the real enum actually using the custom values, and another "dummy enum" just for counting the items. The advantage of this is that you get an enumeration constant with a compatible type as the other enumeration items, available at the same scope as them.

While at it, since you use the style to `ID_ENUM(X)`, you should let `X` be a macro passed to the list, rather than a macro temporarily defined before the list is called. This gives more flexibility, allows better macro names than `X` and reduces clutter. Your code uses some strange combination of that style and the `#define X ... #undef` style.

Full example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ID_ENUM(X)       \
  /*  name       id    */\
    X(TEL_ID,    0x100)  \
    X(ING_ID,    0x200)  \
    X(HEARTBEAT, 0x206)  \
    X(FRAME,     0x400)  \
    X(FRAME2,    0x410)  \

typedef enum 
{
  #define CREATE_ENUM_TX_IDS(name, id) name = id,
  ID_ENUM(CREATE_ENUM_TX_IDS)
} tx_ids_t;

typedef enum
{
  #define CREATE_ENUM_TX_IDS_COUNT(name, id) name##dummy,
  ID_ENUM(CREATE_ENUM_TX_IDS_COUNT) // these won't be used, just for counting

  TX_IDS_N, // the number of items
} tx_ids_count_t;

int main() 
{
  // print all enum items, name + value:
  #define PRINT_ENUM_TX_IDS(name, id) printf("%-10s %#x\n", #name, name);
  ID_ENUM(PRINT_ENUM_TX_IDS)

  // create an array containing one item of every kind:
  tx_ids_t array[] = 
  {
    #define ENUM_TX_IDS(name, id) name,
    ID_ENUM(ENUM_TX_IDS)
  };
  // defensive programming/sanity check:
  _Static_assert(TX_IDS_N == sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array), "Enum size inconsistency");

  puts("");

  // print the array:
  for(size_t i=0; i<TX_IDS_N; i++)
  {
    printf("Array item %d: %#x\n", i, array[i]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
TEL_ID     0x100
ING_ID     0x200
HEARTBEAT  0x206
FRAME      0x400
FRAME2     0x410

Array item 0: 0x100
Array item 1: 0x200
Array item 2: 0x206
Array item 3: 0x400
Array item 4: 0x410
```

Comment: (Although in C23 we will be able to specify the desired integer type of the enum, which makes things easier.)