# In C, can `enum` be made to count backward?

Tags: c, error-handling, enums

I would like to create an enumerated list of negative values for error handling so <0 is an error and >=0 is valid for some function:

```c
int f() {
  if (someerror())
    return ERR_TYPE_2;
  else
    return 0;
}

main() {
  if (f() < 0) blow_up(); 
  else profit(); 
}
```

I know that enumerations in C (`enum`) count up from 0 by default, and I *could* assign them like so:

```c
enum {
  ERR_TYPE_1 = -1,
  ERR_TYPE_2 = -2,
  ERR_TYPE_3 = -3
}
```

or I get arbitrary negative enums "automatically" by starting at an arbitrary negative value for which the enum will never reach:

```c
enum {
  ERR_TYPE_1 = -100,
  ERR_TYPE_2 // -99
  ERR_TYPE_3 // -98 ...
}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to tell `enum` to start at `-1` and count negative instead of  using the methods above?

Update for commenters:

I have no objection to hard-coded error values, in fact that's what I usually do (either as a define or an enum).

This question is really about whether C *officially* supports negative enums in some unknown-to-me syntactic sugar that wasn't forthcoming after some search-fu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible.  Enum identifiers without an explicit value assigned are required to have the value of 1 more that the prior identifier, or 0 for the first one.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.2.2p3 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Enumeration Specifiers:

> If the first enumerator has
> no `=`, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no `=`
> defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by
> adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.

While it's possible that a compiler may support a different ordering as an extension, I'm not aware of any that support such a feature.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise against automatic numbering of error codes.  It creates an awful user experience for the programmer calling your function, who gets an error `-67` and has to go count entries in your header file's error listing (skipping commented lines, naturally).  Much nicer if the error codes have explicit values.  Autonumbering also makes it too easy to change numbering of existing error codes, making it impossible to compare logs from different versions of your software.

But if you insist, keep reading:

---

You can do this using the ["X-MACROS" pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_macro).  The general concept is that they define the list a single time, but generate multiple source code snippets from that list, with the transformation from list to source code changing.

---

myenum.enm

```
ENM_X(ERR_NOTFOUND)
ENM_X(ERR_TOOHARD)
ENM_X(ERR_STACKOVERFLOW)
```

---

```
enum myenum_helper
{
    skipzero,
#define ENM_X(ID) enumreversinghelper_##ID,
#include "myenum.enm"
#undef ENM_X
};

enum myenum
{
#define ENM_X(ID) ID = -enumreversinghelper_##ID,
#include "myenum.enm"
#undef ENM_X
};
```

You can do it without `#include` by relying on the delayed expansion of macros inside macro bodies, but that requires a preprocessor guru to understand and maintain.  This version is pretty straightforward.  As a bonus, you can now `#include` the same file in an `strerror()`-like function that automates mapping numeric codes to names.

On the other hand, if you're willing to delve into the intricacies of the preprocessor macro semantics, you could hide the complicated parts and make usage much nicer:

```
#include "reversed_enum.h"
REVERSED_ENUM(myenum, ERR_NOTFOUND, ERR_TOOHARD, ERR_STACKOVERFLOW)
```

Comment: I have used X macros, and I kinda like them -- within limits. But I never would have thought of this, and I would never recommend it over just writing the enum's identifier list with explicit values.  I don't really see the OP's objection there, or even their objection to just starting with the most negative identifier.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: In the first paragraph I recommend against it as well.  But it is what OP asked for.

Comment: Gotta wonder just how many distinct errors this interface wants to support. Even highly complex interfaces in the wild have a reasonably limited set of possible errors. One possible approach is to define the errors as positive values in a different enum and wrap that in an "error" macro that just negates the value. Then return the result code as a normal integer. Also requires some other macro/function for checking the error. None of this is really worth it IMO. Explicitly-defined values for enum result codes (with clean whitespace for readability) is usually the winner.

Comment: @paddy: "highly complex interfaces in the wild"... https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/tools/Debugging%20Tools%20for%20Windows/winext/manifest/winerror.h   And note that "define the errors as positive values in a different enum" is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There are lots of ways to use X macros when dealing with enums, quite handy although of course hard to read. One always has to answer the question: how hellbent am I on centralizing all code maintenance to one single place in the code? (Kind of thorn myself since I do like X macros, but I always preach KISS>DRY.) Here's an example from an answer I posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831330/584518. It's actually quite similar to the question here.

Answer (score 2):

It is no possible as described in the other answer. However, one could use `__LINE__` predefined macro to achieve this functionality. Just mark one line as a starting point and all other as start marker minus the current line.

```
#define PREV START - __LINE__
enum {
  START = __LINE__ + OPTIONAL_OFFSET,
  ENUM1 = PREV,
  ENUM2 = PREV,
  ENUM3 = PREV,
  ENUM4 = PREV,
}
```

Note that this method is very fragile to newline so use it with a great care if use it at all.

Comment: I was about to propose this very thing myself, then I spotted this answer :) Yeah these solutions are brittle and not really recommended, but they do solve the problem without any macro magic. It will work just fine until someone starts to mess around with it during maintenance :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you know the total number of items needed in advance, here's a simple solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ENUM_ITEMS 3
#define OFFSET 1

typedef enum 
{
  H_ERR_TYPE_1 = ENUM_ITEMS + OFFSET,  // 4
  H_ERR_TYPE_2,                        // 5
  H_ERR_TYPE_3,                        // 6
} helper_enum_t;

typedef enum
{
  ERR_TYPE_1 = ENUM_ITEMS - (int)H_ERR_TYPE_1,  // 3 - 4 = -1
  ERR_TYPE_2 = ENUM_ITEMS - (int)H_ERR_TYPE_2,  // 3 - 5 = -2
  ERR_TYPE_3 = ENUM_ITEMS - (int)H_ERR_TYPE_3,  // 3 - 6 = -3
} negative_enum_t;

int main() 
{
  printf("%d\n",ERR_TYPE_1);
  printf("%d\n",ERR_TYPE_2);
  printf("%d\n",ERR_TYPE_3);
}
```

Output:

```
-1
-2
-3
```